# Posting to a REST API on form submit with Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I am looking through the documentation for a sample of how to handle a submit from an Orbeon form that I gather some data in and then submitting to another application via REST. I am not seeing anything that shows how to do that. Does Orbeon provide functionality to do that or do I need to code some JSP or something else on the backside to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is, that you have to provide/implement the REST service yourself. You aren't restricted to do it in Java, but if this is your preferred language, here's how a very simple servlet would look like. In this case the REST service saves the form in a file in the temp directory.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class FormDumpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FormDumpServlet.class.getName());
    private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS");


    protected Optional<String> makeTempDir() {
        final String dir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        logger.info(String.format("java.io.tmpdir=%s", dir));
        if (dir == null) {
            logger.severe("java.io.tmpdir is null, can't create temp directory");
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        final File f = new File(dir,"form-dumps");
        if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory() && f.canWrite()) {
            return Optional.of(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        if (f.mkdir()) {
            return Optional.of(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        logger.severe(String.format("failed to create temp dir <%s>", f.getAbsolutePath()));
        return Optional.empty();
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = req.getPathInfo();
        if (!path.equalsIgnoreCase("/accept-form")) {
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }
        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = req.getParameterNames();
        while(parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            final String name = parameterNames.nextElement();
            final String value = req.getParameter(name);
            logger.info(String.format("parameter: name=<%s>, value=<%s>", name, value));
        }
        Optional<String> tempPath = makeTempDir();
        if (tempPath.isPresent()) {
            String fn = String.format("%s.xml", FORMAT.format(new Date()));
            File f = new File(new File(tempPath.get()), fn);
            logger.info(String.format("saving form to file <%s>", f.getAbsolutePath()));
            try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f))) {
                req.getReader().lines().forEach((l) -> pw.println(l));
            }
        }
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

You also have to configure a property in `properties-local.xml` which connects the send action for your form (the form with the name `my_form` in your application `my_application`) to the REST endpoint. This property could look as follows:

```xml
<property
        as="xs:string"
        name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.my_application.my_form"
        >
        require-valid
        then save-final
        then send(uri = "http://localhost:8080/my-form-dump-servlet/accept-form")
        then success-message(message = "Success: the form was transferred to the REST service") 
    </property>
```

Comment: Yes I have the REST Service already it is part of another application. I just want to do a HTTP GET/POST/DEL depending on the transaction with  the info from the fields in the form.  for example the REST API offers this https://172.17.17.225/api.php/v1/devices.json then their is a JSON body that is added with the info from the form fields.